# Does the content of the file ever get cached by VFS?

Tags: cache, vfs

If you read a text file for example, does its content ever get cached or is it always the address of the disk that gets cached?

Answer (score 1):

The VFS buffer cache caches the blocks read from a block device, i.e. the contents of files.

There are a handful of caches used by VFS, the buffer cache is described [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596002130/ch14s02.html) (for example, I'm sure there are many other resources out there).